# How to select an html element in playwright with typescript?

Tags: typescript, playwright

Using playwright with typescript I want to select the following html element:

```
<div class="ivu-select-dropdown" style="position: absolute; min-width: 180px; will-change: top, left; transform-origin: center top; top: 135px; left: 339px;" x-placement="bottom-start">
       <ul class="ivu-select-not-found" style="display: none;">
            <li>No matching data</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ivu-select-dropdown-list">
            <li class="ivu-select-item">
                <div class="custom-select-item-for-preview">5Cells</div>
            </li>
            ... and other li elements
```

I looked up the documentation but still have no clue how to use e.g. the class "ivu-select-dropdown" to select that element.

The html structure seems to change, it also could be the following structure before clicking on anything, or I missed to show important elements:

```
<div class="custom-autocomplete-targets ivu-select ivu-select-single ivu-select-small ivu-form-item-error">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="ivu-select-selection"><input type="hidden">
        <div class="">
            <!---->
            <!----> <span class="" style="display: none;"></span> <input type="text" placeholder="Select" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" class="ivu-select-input">
            <!----> <i class="ivu-icon ivu-icon-ios-arrow-down ivu-select-arrow"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ivu-select-dropdown" style="display: none; position: absolute; min-width: 180px; will-change: top, left; transform-origin: center top; top: 135px; left: 339px;" x-placement="bottom-start">
        <ul class="ivu-select-not-found" style="display: none;">
            <li>No matching data</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ivu-select-dropdown-list">
            <li class="ivu-select-item">
                <div class="custom-select-item-for-preview">5Cells</div>
        </li>
        ... and other li elements
```

Comment: According to [this page](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors), it should be `await page.locator(".ivu-select-dropdown");`

Comment: Not clear on that page. Could also have been `await page.locator("#ivu-select-dropdown");`

Comment: It's a **CSS** selector, so it *has* to be `.ivu-select-dropdown`.

Comment: I am not really familiar that a "dot" means CSS element. However, I get an error `strict mode violation: ".ivu-select-dropdown-list" resolved to 14 elements`

Comment: Rip. You could turn off strict mode or find a more specific selector.

Comment: I put the html in my question. Maybe I also can check for the `ul` element?

Comment: A dot means it refers to the class name. A hash refers to the id of the element.

Comment: How can I also search for this class element in the ul element? Is that possible?

Comment: You want to select the drop down or a specific drop down item ?

Comment: In the end I want to select a specific dropdown item.

Comment: Attribute selector with `has` with the class name can probably get you the element? - `.ivu-select-dropdown[x-placement='bottom-start']:has(ul)`

Comment: And that specific item has a unique value, like "5Cells"?

Comment: Yes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an element containing a specific text is hard to do using CSS selectors, using XPath is much easier:

```
let dropDownItem = page.locator("xpath=//li[@class='ivu-select-item']/div[text()='5Cells']");
await dropDownItem.click();
```

Or if you want to click on the `li` element instead of the embedded `div`, use the following selector:

```
let dropDownItem = page.locator("xpath=//li[@class='ivu-select-item']/div[text()='5Cells']/parent::li");
```

You can try with this mock:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Mock</h1>
  <div class="ivu-select-dropdown" style="position: absolute; min-width: 180px; will-change: top, left; transform-origin: center top; top: 50px; left: 50px;" x-placement="bottom-start">
    <ul class="ivu-select-not-found" style="display: none;">
      <li>No matching data</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ivu-select-dropdown-list">
      <li class="ivu-select-item">
        <div class="custom-select-item-for-preview">3Cells</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ivu-select-dropdown-list">
      <li class="ivu-select-item">
        <div class="custom-select-item-for-preview">5Cells</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This requires the texts in the custom drop down to be unique, which can be expected for drop downs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in both cases I get the message `waiting for selector ...` and nothing else happens. It looks like the xpath is still wrong, or it is a weird html construct which changes when you click on the dropdown. I updated that in my  question

Comment: I created a mock of your page locally and tested the xpath expression in Chrome DevTools, where it is working fine. The mock might differ from the actual implementation though.

Comment: Mock has been added to the answer.

Comment: @Alex, what happens when you try selecting it using `await page.getByText('5Cells').click()`?

Comment: I get an error `Error: strict mode violation: "text=5Cells" resolved to 3 elements:` How to select the first, second or third element?

Comment: So the drop down items are not unique or there are multiple drop downs with the same items?

Comment: There is exactly ONE item in the dropdown named `5Cells`, but there might be 2 other dropdowns with the same list. I for sure need to "first" one.

Comment: Ok, so then you need something which is unique for the specific drop down.

Comment: What about `await page.locator(".ivu-select-dropdown").first().getByText('5Cells').click()` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249535/discussion-between-alex-and-bouke).

Answer (score 0):

Try this Alex:

```
await page.locator("(//li[@class='ivu-select-item'])[1]").click()
```

Anyways, go to your browser, open your devtool from your browser and try to find the li you want just changing the index:

```
(//li[@class='ivu-select-item'])[1]
```

or

```
(//li[@class='ivu-select-item'])[2]
```

etc

```
(//li[@class='ivu-select-item'])[X]
```